# Why does the break statement not work while scraping reviews with Selenium and BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, while-loop, break

I am scraping reviews with Selenium and BeautifulSoup in Python but the `break` statement does not work so that the `while` loop continues even after arriving at the last review page of a product. From what I understand it should work as there is no "next page" button on the last review page anymore. Can someone explain why `break` is not working?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

reviewlist= []

ASINs = ['B09SXL3HPG', 'B07TP8LLQZ']
for a in range(len(ASINs)):
    url = 'https://www.amazon.de/dp/' + str(ASINs[a])
    driver.get(url)

    #Accept cookies (only if you need it)
    if a == 0:
        accept_cookies = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='sp-cc-accept']"))).click()

    #Go to all reviews
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-hook='see-all-reviews-link-foot']"))).click()

    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        reviews = soup.find_all('div', {'data-hook': 'review'})
        for item in reviews:
            review = {
                'date': item.find('span', {'data-hook': 'review-date'}).text.strip(),
                'body': item.find('span', {'data-hook': 'review-body'}).text.strip(),
                }
            reviewlist.append(review)

        try:
            next_page_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.a-pagination .a-last'))).click()
            print('click')
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex,"!!!!!!!")
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *From what I understand it should work as there is no "next page" button on the last review page anymore.*

Except there *is*, even though its disabled:

> [image: next page]

So, the `while` probably ends up clicking it endlessly to no effect. I would suggest using as selector <kbd>**`.a-pagination .a-last:not(.a-disabled)`**</kbd> instead of just *`.a-pagination .a-last`*.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much! :) I thought this entire time that because it says 'disabled' this would be considered as a different element.

Comment: @Mina glad to help! yes, `.{class}` selectors select every element *containing* that class. For example `.a-pagination .a-last.a-disabled` would pick the disabled "Next Page" button specifically, even if they had `class="a-disabled a-last btn-grey"`